# How do i improve my program to find the minimum positive number missing in an unsorted array?

Tags: python, arrays

I wrote the following code to solve the puzzle to find the [smallest positive number missing from an unsorted array](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-positive-number-missing-from-an-unsorted-array/).

```
def firstMissingPositive(A):
    i = 1
    for j in A:
        if i - j == 0:
            i += 1
    return I
```

I initialize a variable `i` to `1` since we are only interested in the range `[1, sizeOfList+1]` and as I find the occurence of in in the list I increment the variable to find out whether the next number exist in the list or not. I think my logic is right but it is not. Can anyone please explain why my logic is incorrect.

Comment: *"I think my logic is right but it is not"* - how do you know? What's the failing case?

Comment: You return a capital i; is that a problem? At least it is no where defined if I don't miss anything.

Comment: You assume that your array contains elements starting from 1 which is not correct.. What happens if your array have elements from 19 to 38 ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe , i submitted my code on interview.com and it failed

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"failed"*? Have you tried *testing* it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i submitted my cod and it was tested on a list of numbers my function returned 2 but the right answer was 4, the list was really very big that is why i could not paste it here.

Comment: Then cut it down to a [mcve]; have you done no debugging yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you only do a single take. So imagine a list where `1` is at the very end. You iterate over that list, looking for the `1` in which case `i - j = 0` would be true (btw. that’s `i == j` in readable). You find it at the very last index, so you increment `i` to `2`.

But while going there, you skipped all the other numbers that were not `1`. So you have no idea whether you actually met a `2` before.

In order to use your solution, you would have to repeat that up to `n = len(A)` times, which makes your solution quadratic.

In your linked article, this is described as the “naive solution”:

> A **naive method** to solve this problem is to search all positive integers, starting from 1 in the given array. We may have to search at most n+1 numbers in the given array. So this solution takes O(n^2) in worst case.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that has a complexity of O(n^2). A minor optimization is that we always remove the item from the list which was the lowest positive number so we do not have to iterate over it again.

```
def firstMissingPositive(A):
    return helper(A, 1)

def helper(list, lowest):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return lowest
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        num = list[i]
        if num == lowest:
            del list[i]
            return helper(list, lowest+1)
    return lowest

print firstMissingPositive([1,2,5,6,3]) # -> 4
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming the list actually does have all consecutive, non-repeating integers, except for a single missing entry, which is assumed not to be at the beginning or the end of the list, then this would be a good solution:

```
def firstMissingPositive(A):
    sorted_A = sorted(A)
    for index, value in enumerate(sorted_A):
        if value - sorted_A[0] > index:
            return value - 1
```

this is O(nlogn)